# Independence of Random Variables From Expectation Counter Example

Tags: probability-theory

I know that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, then $\mathbb{E}(XY) = \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$. I also know that the converse is not true, although I cannot seem to find an easy counter-example. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following random variables:
$$
P(X = -1) = P(X = 1) = 1/2\\
P(Y = 0 \mid X = -1) = 1 \\
P(Y = 1 \mid X = 1) = P(Y  = -1 \mid X = 1) = 1/2
$$
Then $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y) = 0$.

Answer (score 6):

Let X be a normally-distributed random variable with $\mu=0$.  Let $Y = X^2$.  Clearly X and Y are not independent. 

But when you calculate their correlation, you will get zero.Because:
$$Cov(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y) = E(X^3) - 0*E(Y) = E(X^3)= 0$$
So X and Y are uncorrelated but not independent.